# Finding image by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have 12 games that I need to sort through that each have a date and img string.  I'm fairly new to jQuery and was wondering what is the best way to accomplish this. Is there a way that I can run this through a loop of some sort rather than having 12 `else`-`if` statements like I currently have (code condensed to 3 for readability)? This code works, I was just looking for the cleaner more concise way of writing it.

```
var now = new Date();
boise = { date: new Date ('May 15, 2012'), img: 'Boise' };
central = { date: new Date ('May 21, 2012'), img: 'Central' };
notreDame = { date: new Date ('May 27, 2012'), img: 'NotreDame' };
    ...
banner = $('#nextGameBanner');
imgDir = 'images/nextGame';


if (now < boise.date ) {
    banner.attr('src', imgDir+boise.img+'.jpg');
}
else if (now < central.date) {
    banner.attr('src', imgDir+central.img+'.jpg');
}
else if (now < notreDame.date) {
    banner.attr('src', imgDir+notreDame.img+'.jpg');
}
    ...
```

HTML

```
<img src="/website/images/nextGame.jpg" id="nextGameBanner" />
```

Comment: Since you are applying the same function across different variables, look into implementing a [partial function](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/) and simply change the variable to be the game name you are referencing.

Comment: @j08691: The moderators prefer that you flag such things for their attention, that way they can move the question and avoid duplicate posts on different sites.

Comment: @muistooshort - it was just a suggestion for the OP. Wasn't sure if that was the best spot and whether it needed to be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (now.getTime() < boise.date.getTime() ) {
    banner.attr('src', imgDir+boise.img+'.jpg');
}
.....
```

In total,

```
var now = new Date();
    objs = { 
        // here I change your 12 variables to a single object, so I can loop over them
        boise : { date: new Date ('May 15, 2012'), img: 'Boise' },
        central : { date: new Date ('May 21, 2012'), img: 'Central' },
        notreDame : { date: new Date ('May 27, 2012'), img: 'NotreDame' }
    },
    banner = $('#nextGameBanner'),
    imgDir = 'images/nextGame';

// making loop with objs

$.each(objs, function(key, singleObj) { 
   // compare time with now and stored time in object
   if (now.getTime() < singleObj.date.getTime() ) {
     // assigning src to image when the condition satisfied
     banner.attr('src', imgDir+ singleObj.img +'.jpg');
     break; // stop the loop when match found
   }
});
```

​
[read about getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: Looks like it should work however I did this and I'm always getting the '.img' from the last object (even though previous dates should have settled the if statement condition) , any ideas?

Comment: @user1394450 check my update answer. Loop should break when match found. I edited that.

Comment: This worked with 1 exception, I cant "break;" I need to "return false;" Thank you very much!